# AudioBuffer's "getChannelData()" equivalent for MediaStream (or MediaStreamAudioSourceNode)?

Tags: audio-recording, web-audio-api, audiocontext, mediastream

I use `AudioContext`'s `decodeAudioData` on an mp3 file, which gives me an `AudioBuffer`. With this audio buffer, I go on to draw a waveform of this mp3 file on a canvas using the data returned by `getChannelData()`.

Now I want to use the same code to draw a waveform of the audio data of a `MediaStream`, which means I need the same kind of input/data. I know a `MediaStream` contains real time information, but there must be a way to access each new data from the `MediaStream` as

> a Float32Array containing the PCM data

which is what the `AudioBuffer`'s `getChannelData` returns.

I tried to wrap the `MediaStream` with a `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` and feed it into an `AnalyserNode` to use `getFloatFrequencyData()` (which returns a `Float32Array`), but I can tell the data is different from the data I get from `getChannelData()`. Maybe it isn't "PCM" data? How can I get "PCM" data?

Hopefully this is clear. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a note that AnalyserNode only samples the data occasionally, but won't process all of it.  I think that matches your scenario well, but just know that if you need all the data (like, you're buffering up the audio), you will need to use ScriptProcessor instead today.

Presuming you just want samples of the data, you can use AnalyserNode, but you should call getFloatTimeDomainData(), not getFloatFrequencyData().  That will give you the PCM data (FrequencyData is giving you the FFT of the PCM data).

Comment: `getFloatTimeDomainData()` doesn't seem return the same kind of data then `getChannelData()` as the result I get from drawing the waveform on the canvas with `getFloatTimeDomainData()` isn't good. Are you sure both arrays represent the same data and are organized the same way?

Comment: If the MediaStream has multiple channels (stereo, say), `AnalyserNode` mixes them to mono.  You'll need to split out the MediaStream data (using a `ChannelSplitterNode` to get the track you want and send that to the analyser.

Comment: @RaymondToy Thanks Raymond, that saved me!! Can you post that as an answer? Or cwilso, can you update your answer to include this addition information?

Comment: Glad that worked for you! I don't think that would be a valid answer to your question.  cwilso has the correct answer for your question.

Comment: let volumes = new Float32Array( meter.frequencyBinCount );

meter.getFloatTimeDomainData( volumes ) worked for me, tested side by side, almost exact  same as values as event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

Answer (score 1):

create MediaStreamDestination with audiocontext and then new MediaRecorder from the stream,

```
var options = {mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=pcm'};
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```